# 10k moderator tools - view flags button

Tags: discussion

Ever since the the new top bar went live I haven't seen the flags button. Is it broken, haven't I been paying enough attention or is it coincidence and I missed them?

Comment: Normal flags working for me, it is just not there if there are 0. I dont have 10k tools, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @Kortuk I used to get this orange/brown'ish blob next to my badges, indicating that there were flags waiting to be reviewed. Haven't seen that (or anything similar) in days.

Comment: I have only seen maybe 10 flags in 3 days, but it might just be chance for me also.

Comment: [It's back!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6vy7I.jpg)

Comment: I hadn't seen the red and yellow alert thingies lately either.  I just got a yellow flag indicator this morning.  I dealt with the flag, but yellow alert still keeps telling me there is a flag.  When I click on it, there are no flags.  Apparently now these things can't be cleared.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes it takes quite a while to clear.